# Photoshop export gradient ( .grd files )

Tags: css, photoshop

I'm trying to write a tool for converting photoshop gradients to css gradients using sass/compass. From what I've read the .grd is a proprietary format for which documentation is not available. Would the built in scripting be able to get at this info?

**EDIT**: [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_javascript_ref.pdf) is a link to the scripting docs (I couldn't find anything)

**EDIT 2**: http://www.tonton-pixel.com/blog/photoshop-scripting/json-sample-scripts/parse-gradients-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the command-line, then [cptutils](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/jjg/en/code/cptutils.html) can do this.  If not, then this [online version](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cptutils-online/) may do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Been searching for a while to find something for this. All I came up with is http://csshat.com
Which is awesome in it's own right.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gradientapp.com/

its a great tool for creating css gradients

Comment: there are lots of css generators, but im trying to export gradients from existing psds.

Comment: i see, sorry i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the gradient on an object and get the hexadecimal value of the polarities.

I do not see the advantage of the tool you're describing. However, see if [this link](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/gimp-add-ons-types-installation-management) helps. Found in a related article [how to read .grd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459680/program-library-to-read-photoshop-gradient-grd-file) file.